# Attempt to read property "value" on bool

Tags: php, mysql

```php
<?php

define("limit",20);

$pdo= new PDO("sqlite:products.db",null,null,
                [ PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                  PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE=>PDO::FETCH_OBJ]
            );
try{
    
    $pagecurrent=(int)($_GET["p"]??1);
    $offset=($pagecurrent-1)*limit.",".limit;
    $limit="LIMIT $offset"; 
    
    if(!empty($_GET["q"])){
        $req=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE city LIKE:city $limit");
        $req->execute(["city"=>("%{$_GET['q']}%")]);
        
        $sqlreq=$pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as value FROM products  WHERE city LIKE:city $limit");
        $sqlreq->execute(["city"=>("%{$_GET['q']}%")]);
        
    }else{
        
        $req=$pdo->query("SELECT * FROM products $limit");
        $sqlreq=$pdo->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as value FROM products");
    
    }

    $elements=$req->fetchAll();
    $totale=$sqlreq->fetch()->value;
    
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

when I do a fetch on sqlreq I get a bool instead of the value of "value"
on the other hand if I use query instead of prepare everything works normally
I would like to know where is the problem in my code

Comment: You should include the whole error message, so we can tell where it originates. However, this is a common error, so if you google it you will find the reason.

Comment: If `$sqlreq` is a boolean, then the query must have failed, its the only possibility

Comment: Out of interest, WHY are you placing a LIMIT on a COUNT() Query which will only ever return one row?

Answer (score 0):

Change `LIKE:city` to `LIKE :city`

The space is required. And remove the LIMIT it makes zero sense

Comment: thank you for your reply
I tried to modify the code